# How can I search multiple words in the same regex?

Tags: r, regex, lapply, gsub

I've got a list of specific words to remove a list of sentences.  Do I have to loop over the list and apply a function to each regex or can I somehow call them all at once? I've tried to do so with lapply, but I'm hoping to find a better way.

```
 string <- 'This is a sample sentence from which to gather some cool 
 knowledge'

 words <- c('a','from','some')

lapply(words,function(x){
  string <- gsub(paste0('\\b',words,'\\b'),'',string)
})
```

My desired output is:
`This is sample sentence which to gather cool knowledge.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can collapse across your character vector of words-to-remove with the regex OR operator(`"|"`) sometimes referred to as the "pipe" symbol.

```
gsub(paste0('\\b',words,'\\b', collapse="|"), '', string)
[1] "This is  sample sentence  which to gather  cool \n knowledge"
```

Or:

```
gsub(paste0('\\b',words,'\\b\\s{0,1}', collapse="|"), '', string)
[1] "This is sample sentence which to gather cool \n knowledge"
```

Comment: +1 but I'd even use `gsub(paste0('\\b',words,'\\b\\s*', collapse="|"),'',string)` to get rid of the whitespaces, so that you'd end up having `[1] "This is sample sentence which to gather cool \n knowledge"`.

Comment: Agree there might be a desire to remove a trailing space but I probably would only remove at most one with "\\s{0,1}"

Answer (score 1):

```
string<-'This is a sample sentence from which to gather some cool knowledge'
words<-c('a', 'from', 'some')
library(tm)
string<-removeWords(string, words = words)
string
[1] "This is  sample sentence  which to gather  cool knowledge"
```

With the tm library you can use the `removeWords()`.

or you can loop with gsub like:

```
string<-'This is a sample sentence from which to gather some cool knowledge'
words<-c('a', 'from', 'some')
for(i in 1:length(words)) {
  string<-gsub(pattern = words[i], replacement = '', x = string)
}
string
[1] "This is  sample sentence  which to gather  cool knowledge"
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `"|"` to use or in the regex :

```
string2 <- gsub(paste(words,'|',collapse =""),'',string)

> string2
[1] "This is sample sentence which to gather cool knowledge"
```